# Django user.is_authenticated reversed

Tags: django

In my template if user is anonymous,it would show Register button. So I use

```
 {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Log out
 {% else %}
  Log in
```

But when I test it. It reversed.

Comment: What do you mean by "when i test it"?

Comment: Are you sure `user` is in context of template? Try adding `{{ user }}` outside this if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry I login into admin site and I forgot to logout.